# OpenGL 3.1 lighting messed up, using phong shading

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, freeglut, glu

After many painful hours of attempting to figure out why my lighting is messed up I am still at a loss.

The OpenGL normals are correct (backface culling does not cause any of my triangles to disappear)

I calculate my normals in order to interpolate for lighting, all the triangles on the same faces also have the same normals.

If any one has any thoughts that would be appreciated.

I am definitely new to OpenGL, so that is a bit obvious in my code. 
[image: incorrect lighting]

here are my shaders:

- vertex shader

  ```
  #version 330 core

  layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;
  layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;
  in   vec3 vNormal;

  out vec3 fragmentColor; // Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
  uniform mat4 MVP;
  uniform mat4 transformMatrix;
  uniform vec4 LightPosition;

  // output values that will be interpretated per-fragment
  out  vec3 fN;
  out  vec3 fE;
  out  vec3 fL;

  void main()
  {


      fN = vNormal;
      fE = Position.xyz;
      fL = LightPosition.xyz;

      if( LightPosition.w != 0.0 ) {
          fL = LightPosition.xyz - Position.xyz;
      }



      // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
      vec4 v = vec4(Position,1); // Transform in homoneneous 4D vector
      gl_Position = MVP * v;
      //gl_Position = MVP * v;



      // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
      // to produce the color of each fragment
      //fragmentColor = vertexColor; // take out at some point
  }
  ```
- and the fragmentShader, using phong shading

  ```
  #version 330
  //out vec3 color;

  // per-fragment interpolated values from the vertex shader
  in  vec3 fN;
  in  vec3 fL;
  in  vec3 fE;

  out vec4 fColor;

  uniform vec4 AmbientProduct, DiffuseProduct, SpecularProduct;
  uniform mat4 ModelView;
  uniform vec4 LightPosition;
  uniform float Shininess;

  in vec3 fragmentColor; // Interpolated values from the vertex shaders

  void main()
  {

      // Normalize the input lighting vectors
      vec3 N = normalize(fN);
      vec3 E = normalize(fE);
      vec3 L = normalize(fL);

      vec3 H = normalize( L + E );

      vec4 ambient = AmbientProduct;

      float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
      vec4 diffuse = Kd*DiffuseProduct;

      float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), Shininess);
      vec4 specular = Ks*SpecularProduct;

      // discard the specular highlight if the light's behind the vertex
      if( dot(L, N) < 0.0 ) {
      specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      }

      fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
      fColor.a = 1.0;

      //color = vec3(1,0,0);

      // Output color = color specified in the vertex shader,
      // interpolated between all 3 surrounding vertices
      //color = fragmentColor;
  }


  void setMatrices()
  {
      GLfloat FoV = 45; // the zoom of the camera 

      glm::vec3 cameraPosition(4,3,3), // the position of your camera, in world space // change to see what happends
      cameraTarget(0,0,0),         // where you want to look at, in world space
      upVector(0,-1,0);

      // Projection matrix : 45° Field of View, 4:3 ratio, display range : 0.1 unit <-> 100 units
      glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(FoV, 3.0f / 3.0f, 0.001f, 100.0f); // ratio needs to change here when the screen size/ratio changes

      // Camera matrix
      glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
          cameraPosition, // Camera is at (4,3,3), in World Space
          cameraTarget, // and looks at the origin
          upVector  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
      );

      // Model matrix : an identity matrix (model will be at the origin)
      glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);  // Changes for each model !

      // Our ModelViewProjection : multiplication of our 3 matrices
      glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model * transformMatrix; //matrix multiplication is the other way around


      // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform.
      // Only at initialisation time.
      GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
      // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader,
      // in the "MVP" uniform
      // For each model you render, since the MVP will be different (at least the M part)
      glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

      RotationID = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"transformMatrix");

      //lighting
      cubeNormal = glGetAttribLocation( programID, "vNormal" );


  }
  void setBuffers()
  {
      // Get a vertex array object
      GLuint VAO;
      glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
      glBindVertexArray(VAO);

      glUseProgram(programID);

      // cube buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &CubeVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeBufferData), CubeBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.

      // cube normal objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &CubeNormalbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeNormalbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(CubeNormalBufferData), CubeNormalBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.




      //octahedron buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &OctaVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, OctaVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(octahedronBufData), octahedronBufData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.

      //tetrahedron buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &TetraVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TetraVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tetrahedronBufData), tetrahedronBufData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.

      //dodecahedron buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &DodecaVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, DodecaVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(dodecahedronBufData), dodecahedronBufData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.

      //icosahedron buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &icosaVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, icosaVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(icosahedronBufData), icosahedronBufData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.

      //sphere buffer objects
      glGenBuffers(1, &sphereVertexbuffer); // Generate 1 buffer, put the resulting identifier in vertexbuffer
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereVertexbuffer); // The following commands will talk about our 'vertexbuffer' buffer
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sphereBufData), sphereBufData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // Give our vertices to OpenGL.


      glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
      glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

      // lighting stuff



      // Initialize shader lighting parameters
      point4 light_position= { 0.0, 20.0, -10.0, 0.0 };
      color4 light_ambient ={ 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
      color4 light_diffuse ={ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
      color4 light_specular ={ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

      color4 material_ambient ={ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
      color4 material_diffuse ={ 1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0 };
      color4 material_specular ={ 1.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0 };
      float  material_shininess = 20.0;

      color4 ambient_product;
      color4 diffuse_product;
      color4 specular_product;
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          ambient_product[i] = light_ambient[i] * material_ambient[i];
          diffuse_product[i] = light_diffuse[i] * material_diffuse[i];
          specular_product[i] = light_specular[i] * material_specular[i];
      }
      //printColor("diffuse", diffuse_product);
      //printColor("specular", specular_product);

      glUniform4fv( glGetUniformLocation(programID, "AmbientProduct"),
        1, ambient_product );
      glUniform4fv( glGetUniformLocation(programID, "DiffuseProduct"),
        1, diffuse_product );
      glUniform4fv( glGetUniformLocation(programID, "SpecularProduct"),
        1, specular_product );

      glUniform4fv( glGetUniformLocation(programID, "LightPosition"),
        1, light_position );

      glUniform1f( glGetUniformLocation(programID, "Shininess"),
       material_shininess );

  }
  ```

and some more....

```
void display()
{

    setMatrices(); // initilize Matrices
    // Use our shader
    //glUseProgram(programID);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 


    // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                                // size
        GL_FLOAT,                         // type
        GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
        0,                                // stride
        (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
    );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices   

    // enum platosShapes{tet, cube, octah, dodec, icos};
    switch(shapeInUse)
    {
        case tet:
            {

                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TetraVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4*3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle // need to know amount of vertices here // and change to triangle strips accordingly
            }
            break;
        case cube:
            {

                //GLuint cubeNormal = glGetAttribLocation( programID, "vNormal" ); 
                glEnableVertexAttribArray( cubeNormal );
                glVertexAttribPointer( cubeNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                (const GLvoid *) (sizeof(CubeNormalBufferData)) );
                //glDisableVertexAttribArray( cubeNormal );



                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle // need to know amount of vertices here // and change to triangle strips accordingly
            }
            break;
        case octah:
            {
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, OctaVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 8*3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle // need to know amount of vertices here // and change to triangle strips accordingly
            }
            break;
        case dodec:
            {
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, DodecaVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 5 * 6); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle // need to know amount of vertices here // and change to triangle strips accordingly
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, (5 * 6) + 1, 30);
                //glutSolidDodecahedron();
                //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,5*12);
            }
            break;
        case icos:
            {
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, icosaVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*20); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle // need to know amount of vertices here // and change to triangle strips accordingly
            }
            break;
        case sphere:
            {
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereVertexbuffer);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
                    3,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                );
                //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cnt2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 100);
            }
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glFlush();

}
```

and some more........

```
void calculateNormals(GLfloat bufData[], GLfloat normBufData[], int size) // probalby works
{
    int count = 0;
    GLfloat temp[9];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        temp[count] = bufData[i];
        count++;

        if((i+1) % 9 == 0)
        {
            count = 0;

            //for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            //{
            //  cout << temp[i] << "!,";
            //  if((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            //      cout << "\n";
            //}

            calculateCross(temp, normBufData);
        }
    }

    printNormals(normBufData, size);
}
void calculateCross(GLfloat bufData[], GLfloat normBufData[]) // probably works
{
    static int counter = 0; // need to reset in bettween new buffers

    glm::vec3 C1;
    glm::vec3 C2;
    glm::vec3 normal;

    //cout << bufData[0] << "," << bufData[1] << "," << bufData[2] << " buf 1 \n"; 
    //cout << bufData[3] << "," << bufData[4] << "," << bufData[5] << " buf 2 \n"; 
    //cout << bufData[6] << "," << bufData[7] << "," << bufData[8] << " buf 3 \n\n"; 



    //C1.x = bufData[3] - bufData[0];
    //C1.y = bufData[4] - bufData[1];
    //C1.z = bufData[5] - bufData[2];

    //C2.x = bufData[6] - bufData[0];
    //C2.y = bufData[7] - bufData[1];
    //C2.z = bufData[8] - bufData[2];

    C1.x = bufData[0] - bufData[3];
    C1.y = bufData[1] - bufData[4];
    C1.z = bufData[2] - bufData[5];

    C2.x = bufData[0] - bufData[6];
    C2.y = bufData[1] - bufData[7];
    C2.z = bufData[2] - bufData[8];

    //C2.x = bufData[6] - bufData[0];
    //C2.y = bufData[7] - bufData[1];
    //C2.z = bufData[8] - bufData[2];

    //cout << C1.x << " 1x \n";
    //cout << C1.y << " 1y \n";
    //cout << C1.z << " 1z \n";

    //cout << C2.x << " 2x \n";
    //cout << C2.y << " 2y \n";
    //cout << C2.z << " 2z \n";

    normal = glm::cross(C1, C2);

    //cout << "\nNORMAL : " << normal.x << "," << normal.y << "," << normal.z << " counter = " << counter << "\n";

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            normBufData[counter] = normal.x;
            normBufData[counter + 1] = normal.y;
            normBufData[counter + 2] = normal.z;

        }
        counter+=3;
    }






}
```

and main.....

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(700, 700);    // Window Size

    glutCreateWindow("Michael - Lab 3");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutTimerFunc(10, timeFucn, 10);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enable depth test
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one

    GenerateSphere(); // this function generates points for the sphere

    programID = LoadShader( "VertexShader.glsl", "FragmentShader.glsl" ); // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders

    setBuffers(); // initilize buffers

    calculateNormals(CubeBufferData,CubeNormalBufferData,108); // calculate norms
    //printNormals(CubeNormalBufferData);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're drawing your half or your triangles backwards.

Comment: By the way, back-face culling doesn't have anything to do with normals.

Comment: Do you mean the order of the points being drawn or the faces backwards? Because when i enable back face culling all my triangles are still there.

Comment: I just meant the normal of the triangle that OpenGl uses when determining if a polygon should be drawn when culling is enabled

Comment: @MikeCasa: Face culling is not based on normals, it's based on the winding. Vertices drawn in clockwise order on the screen are considered backface, counterclockwise frontface. So your normals may be wrong; you can not test this with face culling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to bind the buffer object with normals before calling `glVertexAttribPointer( cubeNormal, 3,....);`. Therefore, the actual data for normals is taken from the color buffer, which causes weirdest Phong evaluation result.

BTW, nice coding style :)

Comment: cool, thank you. Strangely I can only get the new working code to run on an nvidia graphics card. Also does it make sense to move the glVertexAttribPointer stuff to the setBuffers() and then just call glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeNormalbuffer); and glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeVertexbuffer); in the display()?

Comment: 1. It has to work on ATI as well. Are shader info logs OK?
2. No, glVertexAttribPointer should be called on every draw call right after the corresponding buffer binding (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER).

Comment: turns out I was doing quite a bit wrong, depending on the defaults of whatever graphics card, the outcome changed. But this only mattered because off all the stuff I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Phong and Gouraud shadings are not applicable to objects with all planar surfaces, e.g. a cube.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of appearing in this cube, and when I sent its normal values, I noticed that I sent the offset value incorrectly and fixed the problem.